# Angular2 Jasmine SpyOn Method Does Not Exist

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have defined an interface and opaque token as follows

```
export let AUTH_SERVICE = new OpaqueToken('auth.service');

export interface AuthService {
    logIn(): void;
    logOut(): void;
}
```

In my test class I provide a stubbed version of `AuthService`, i.e.,

```
@Injectable()
class AuthServiceStub implements AuthService {
    logIn(): void {}
    logOut(): void {}
}
```

and set up my test `beforeEach` as follows

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
            providers: [
                {provide: AUTH_SERVICE, useValue: AuthServiceStub}
            ]
        });
    }));
```

I then started to write the test, i.e.,

```
it('should call log in on AuthService', () => {
        let authService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AUTH_SERVICE);
        spyOn(authService, 'logIn');
        // expect will go here
});
```

but I get the following error

```
 Error: <spyOn> : logIn() method does not exist
```

Can't see what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

That's because you're using `useValue` property in the provider object. That means the injected value will be the `AuthServiceStub` class itself. What you want instead, is its instance that actually have those methods.

To make the test works, replace `useValue` with `useClass`. This will make the Angular's dependency injection system to actually instantiate the service when the provider is created and your call `fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AUTH_SERVICE);` will return a proper object.

Alternatively you could instantiate the class manually:

```
it('should call log in on AuthService', () => {
    let AuthService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(AUTH_SERVICE);
    let authService = new AuthService();
    spyOn(authService, 'logIn');
    // expect will go here
});
```

Still, `useClass` is a better solution, since it will handle all future injections that the `AuthService` might need.